# Unity Build for iOS : Not able to change Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

In unity, already signed in and activated license. But still its repeatedly saying 'Activate Licence to enable build'. Not allowing me to change bundle identifier. How to fix ?

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in with a verified account?

Comment: @AffanShahab, yes. Even I tried manual activation also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got problem fixed by Clicking Toon Racer->Activate in Unity menu. Then added purchase information and serial numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to click on 'Account' and verify if you are logged with the account you've activated, if yes try to sign out and sign in again.
If nothing is changed from the 'Account' tab click 'go to your account' and verify if your account is activated correctly.
After that if nothing work i would go with a fresh install of unity.